# WP e-Commerce USPS Shipping debugging Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a WP site using WP e-Commerce plugin. I'm using USPS shipping and flat rate shipping. In checkout, you can pick flat rate or usps priority mail. If you pick flat rate, the grand total is updated in an ajaxy way. If you pick priority mail, the grand total changes but without adding the priority mail shipping cost.

It's not giving me the correct order total only when picking priority mail. For example...

product price $20.00
usps priority mail shipping $5.00
total $20.00

Even weirder, at first the page displays the correct price, but one second later changes to the product price less the shipping costs.

It's something that has to do with ajax, because when you click on the radio button, it changes the grand total. So I'm thinking it's probably a javascript conflict. I have already checked several files and tweaked them but I can't make it work. I don't debug a lot of javascript, so I don't know exactly how to proceed.

What tools can I use or how can I use them to find out what's subtracting the shipping cost from the grand total a second after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).  This will allow you to set a breakpoint in the JavaScript, and inspect exactly what it's doing, as it's doing it.  It will also allow you to inspect any AJAX requests and responses.